# Invalid field project for division in Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am trying to do a division of 2 columns that are the results of `COUNT` in Pig:

```
a = LOAD 'file.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (ID:chararray, Name:chararray, Result:chararray)
b = filter a by $1=='123';
c = filter a by $1=='123' and $2='Win';
d = foreach (group b by $1) generate group as da_id, count(b) as total;
e = foreach (group c by $1) generate group as da_id, count(c) as total_wins;
f = join d by da_id, e by da_id;
g = foreach (group f by $0) generate group as da_id, f::total_wins/f::total as ratio;
```

However, I get the error

```
Invalid field projection. Projected field [f::total_wins] does not exist in schema
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

total and total_wins are part of relation d and e respectively.Use below code

```
g = foreach (group f by $0) generate group as da_id, e::total_wins/d::total as ratio;
```

Comment: @user6347191 Can you describe the relations d,e,f and post it here? Describe d;Describe e;Describe f;

Comment: d is `{da_id: chararray, total: long}`, e is `{da_id: chararray, total_wins: long}`,  f is `{d::da_id: chararray, d::total:long, e::da_id:chararray, e::total_wins:long}`